# Using epoch UNIX timestamp in time series analysis

Tags: time-series, forecasting, multivariate-analysis, data-transformation

I'm currently working on time series forecasting. My data uses a UNIX timestamp.

Firstly, what's your opinion on using a UNIX timestamp?

The problem I'm facing is that I want a trend line e.g. Power trend y = a * x^b
Long story short I have/can get a and b. And x is my input. But since x is a 10 digit timestamp, if I do x^b I will get a really big number (I'm getting an overflow).
In my case b is quite big and a is very small.... The net result wouldn't cause an overflow..
So my problem is a large number, that being the timestamp.

How can I overcome this?

Also by using a UNIX timestamp, would I be right in saying that an exponential fit's (0,1) point would be 1/1/1970? Even if my data is 2007-2010?

The only way I see is is a hacky date adjustment. Hoping for a better idea.

If it makes any difference I'm using Python ;) and my data is in daily intervals.

Comment: This is hard to follow. Can you provide a simple, concrete example of what you're doing & what the problem is?

Comment: The problem is a big timestamp as my x axis, looking for a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual solution in statistics and machine learning for numerical scale problems is just to standardize, that is, to subtract a variable by its mean and divide by its standard deviation.

But seeing as `x` only as day-level precision, you may as well convert `x` to a count of days since a fixed date (such as the minimum).

> I'm using Python ;)

What on earth are you winking about?

Comment: Thank you, timestamps are never a good idea are they? So is it always best to reindex a time series into its smallest periods like days and start from 0... 0 being your first point

Comment: @ovg I'm not sure about the "never" and "always", but I guess it's hard to think of a situation where POSIX timestamps are the ideal form for input to a regression model. Although second-level precision is indeed what one has in many cases, the zero point of 1970-00-00T00:00:00Z is unlikely to be useful. (If I answered your question to your satisfaction, you can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark under the voting arrows.)